# How do i correctly show my modal video using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a local video that I need to show in the modal window that is currently stuck behind my header. I tried messing with the indexes but to no avail and I'm stumped. My goal is to have my video autoplay in a modal window after the page loads automatically with the option to play open it again if the user clicks my logo. I really new to bootstrap but I thought that this would be a nice looking effect. [This](http://www.alphaleague.gg/) is my site currently.

```
<div class="ol-Introvid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymvid">
    <img src="images/Logo_white.png">
</div>

<div id="mymvid" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" style=" width:100%;">
                <div style=" width: 350px; height: 315;" src="images/video/Alpha League Trailer.mp4"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `div` tag for embedding a video? That's a first. The `src` attribute on the `div` tag is invalid markup

Comment: yea. Im self taught when it comes to css html ect. As you can see. I dont use multimedia much except for pictures but the current standard requires it so creating my own player in css is very challenging for me.... Im still trying to comprehend the modal markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting a workaround for your problem

```
<body>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style=" width:100%;">
          <video id="player" width="400" controls>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<div id="button" style="display:none">
<button id="play">
Play again
</button>
</div>
```

Add the required `jquery` and `boostrap` links like below I have used `Jquery`  to complete yourr problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

To play the video on page load use `$(document).ready(function()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myModal").modal('show');

   $('#player')[0].play();
});
```

To close the modal after couple of seconds use `setTimeout` function

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

$("#myModal").modal('hide');
document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
}, 3000);
```

And open the modal and play the video on button click

```
$(document).on('click','#play',function(){
 $("#myModal").modal('show');
  $('#player')[0].play();
});
```

Here iS  Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/j1dmenxq/3/